# Is there any rules of the 'th' sound in phonological?

Tags: pronunciation

I know well, the tongue is exactly going to the teeth in between(upper&under) when sounded. 
Yet, my point is that Do I have to place the tongue at there all the time?

For example, "Whats' the matter?" and "What's that?"

these two are not so easy to do sound exactly (a /s/ and followed by a /th/).

When sounding them, the tongue is only placed behind of upper teeth.

Either it has obviously to be placed in between or that doesn't matter in speaking, I am really in curious.

Thanks

Comment: Exactly how "th" (as /θ/ or /ð/) is articulated varies considerably according to several factors (which specific speaker, how carefully he's speaking, what phonemes come before and after it, etc.). Personally, the tip of *my* tongue is usually *way* back behind the teeth when I articulate /ð/ after /s/ in, say, *"What's the matter?"*. But it's much further forward if /ð/ occurs at the start of a *stressed* syllable such as *"How's **this** for an example?"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks a lot, I'd really like to appreciate for your answer.

Comment: @ HyoinHa: I don't know how many [reputation points](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) you need to be able to upvote *comments* - but if you stick around on ELU long enough to acquire that privilege, you can always come back to this question and upvote it later, if you can't do it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say the tongue is between the teeth, I assume you are talking about the tongue sticking out slightly, but not actually needing to touch the lower teeth.

Generally, to say /θ/ (as in **th**in) or /ð/ (as in **th**is) there are two options:
(1) the first is where the tip of the tongue is at the lower part of the upper teeth (with the tongue coming out slightly), or 
(2) the second where the tip of the tongue is against the back of the upper teeth (and the tongue does not protrude).

Some people use both options, and adjust according to context. Some people use mainly one.